# Android Emulator is not working in Android Studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-emulator

Recently, I updated my Android studio 3.3 to 4.0 version. I am unable to run Android Emulator.

## Errors as follows:

Emulator: emulator: ERROR: It seems too many emulator instances are running on this machine. Aborting.

Emulator: WARNING: jdwp port creation fails, Icebox will not work.

Kindly, help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Could you please post the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Hi,Welcome to SO. Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Disable Anti virus protection of your system and launch application again, its worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling to get out this error for two days and suddenly magic happened !
I just opened my anti-virus protection software and granted full access (internet) to this "qemo-system.i386"
[This is what I did in anti-virus protection software/firewall/applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx0Gt.png)